# worksheet as vba class module property - runtime error 9

Tags: class, excel, vba

I have the following vba class module called `clsAgent`:

```
Option Explicit

Private pAgentSheetName As String
Private pAgentSheet As Worksheet


Public Property Get AgentSheetName() As String
    AgentSheetName = pAgentSheetName
End Property

Public Property Let AgentSheetName(AgentSheetName As String)
    pAgentSheetName = AgentSheetName
End Property


Public Property Get AgentSheet() As Worksheet
    AgentSheet = pAgentSheet
End Property

Public Property Let AgentSheet(AgentSheet As Worksheet)
    pAgentSheet = AgentSheet
End Property
```

Here's my class instantiation in a different module:

```
Sub test_agent_class()
    Dim agent1 As clsAgent
    Set agent1 = New clsAgent

    Set agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets(agent1.AgentSheetName)
    Debug.Print agent1.AgentSheet.Name
End Sub
```

When I run `test_agent_class()`, however, I get an error: `run-time error 9
subscript out of range`.  The following line gets highlighted in yellow:`Set agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets(agent1.AgentSheetName)`.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062666/run-time-error-9-in-vba-script), but I don't get what the problem is because `agent1.AgentSheetName` is a string.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Per the first answer I added the line:

```
agent1.AgentSheetName = "agentsFullOutput.csv"
```

right after the class in instantiated. Now I get an error:

```
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `pAgentSheet` is a `Worksheet` which is an object type, you need to use `Set` to assign it within the `Property Let` procedure. It's also probably clearer to use [Property Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264263.aspx) instead of [Property Let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278788.aspx) like this:

```
Public Property Set AgentSheet(AgentSheet As Worksheet)
    Set pAgentSheet = AgentSheet
End Property
```

If you use a `Property Let` procedure then you do not use `Set` when calling the procedure (but you still need it within the procedure) so the call would be `agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets(agent1.AgentSheetName)`

If you use a `Property Set` procedure then you must use `Set` when calling the procedure (and also within the procedure) so the call would be `Set agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets(agent1.AgentSheetName)`

[This VB6 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5049557/2127508) might explain things more clearly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have not assigned a string to `agent1.AgentSheetName`.  So you are trying to set `agent1.AgentSheet` to the worksheet whose name is the empty string.  I doubt that you have such a sheet.  You should start by assigning a value to `agent1.AgentSheetName`.

Comment: good call.  I still get an error, albeit a different one.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: error is thrown on the following line: `et agent1.AgentSheet = Worksheets(agent1.AgentSheetName)`